# unable to display data from Javascript sourced data in datatable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have been trying to display `Javascript sourced data` in the datatable. But it does not work. I tried this [link](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html). What I did is:

**JS:**

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
]

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );

    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine" },
            { "title": "Browser" },
            { "title": "Platform" },
            { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

In the **HTML** section, I did not find anything in the [link](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html). I have checked in several variation but data is not being displayed. i.e. I added table in html or `<div id="demo"></demo>`

**NB:** I have added the script at the bottom section of body. Other example works except it that is, displaying JS data.

Comment: well, it works right away -> http://jsfiddle.net/x71ah83q/ so you probably have some errors elsewhere preventing this script to be executed.

Comment: @davidkonrad I have fixed the issue. You were correct that something is preventing. I was getting error: `K is undefined error` because I used older version script of datatable. thanks for help